# Electrical potential of an infinite sheet

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

say we have a 2D sheet which stetches infinitely across $x$ and $y$ with a charge density σ. then at any point z above the sheet the electric field E is just the electric field in the z direction because the other electric fields cancel each other out.

my question is does the potential from the sheet work the same way. 
ie (does the x potential to the right get canceled out with x potential from right)

Comment: Potential is a scalar, not a vector, so it doesn't have components.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier by probably_someone potential is a scalar, so doesn't have components to cancel each other. Typically when we speak about the electric field from a sheet, we think of a metal, ie a material with high (ideally perfect) conductivity. In such materials electric fields cannot exist, because the electrons would move to cancel it. Hence, there cannot be any potential difference between different parts of the sheet and it all must have the same potential.

Answer (score 0):

In loose terms, the electric potential at any point in space is defined as amount of work someone needs to perform to move a positive unit charge from infinity to that point.

The assumption here is that the point of interest has some electric field in and around it. If there was no field, a charge could be brought in without doing any work.

Another, equivalent, way to define the electric potential at a point is the amount of work the field will perform by moving a unit charge from that point to infinity.

So, in the first definition of electric potential, someone had to push the charge against the field to get it to the point of interest. In the second case, the field was pushing the charge to get it to infinity. The bottom line here is that the electric potential is defined and caused by the electric field. No field - no potential.

NOTE: here, to simplify matters, we assume that the work is positive, i.e., if someone is pushing a positive charge toward some point in space, it is done against the field. If the field was of the opposite sign, the charge would move by itself, so the work "someone" performed would be negative.

You have correctly determined that the electric field above (and below) the sheet will be pointing up (and down), only z component being present. This field is what determines the electric potential anywhere in space, assuming there is nothing else in space to distort it.

Since the sheet is infinite, the electric field will be uniform and will stretch, up and down, to infinity. Because of that, the electric potential, the amount of work such field will perform on a unit charge, will be infinite as well, i.e., the field will continue pushing the charge, with the same force, forever (neglecting here that the charge won't be able to accelerate beyond the speed of light).

If we had a charged sphere instead of an infinite plane, the electric field, associated with that sphere, would decrease with distance from the sphere, which makes for a more interesting (and more realistic) case.

If we put a unit charge (of the opposite sign) near the sphere, where the field is strong, the charge would be pushed pretty hard at the beginning and some good amount of work will be performed before the charge moves far away from the sphere where the field is weak and not much of additional work can be done. So we can say that the electric potential near the charged sphere is high.

If, to start with, we put a unit charge far away from the sphere, where the field is weak, the charge will also be pushed, but the amount of work done won't be significant, even though, theoretically, this pushing will also continue to infinity.

In summary, if you know the field, you can determine the potential.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Yes". If you are above the sheet at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, then the electric field produced by a charge at $(x_q, y_q)$ has the horizontal components canceled by the charge at $(-x_q, -y_q)$--so in the end, after considering the entire space of $(x_q, y_q)$, there is only field in the $z$ direction.

This "look at the trees" view of the problem's symmetries misses "the forest" entirely:

At fixed $z$, the infinite sheet looks the same for *any* $(x, y)$. That is: the problem has complete translational symmetry in the $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ directions--so that the resulting electric field cannot have a symmetry breaking horizontal component. It must be that:

$$ \vec E(x, y, z) = \hat z E(z) $$.

But wait, there is more: From any point in space, the charge distribution appears as to fill $2\pi$ steradians with a uniform plane--and that is independent of distance from the plane.

Looking along the normal to the plane (say you are at $(0,0,z)$), an element of solid angle sees:

$$ dq = \sigma z^2 d\Omega$$ Coulombs, which produces an electric field (magnitude)

$$ dE \propto \frac{dq}{z^2} = \sigma d\Omega,$$

which is independent of $z$. The fact that an infinite plane appears the same from all distances means the electric field must be distance independent:

$$ \vec E(x,y,z) = E_0\hat z,$$

which it is, of course with:

$$ E_0 = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$$

Per Nick's comment: one can use similar arguments for the potential. Horizontal symmetry requires that it not be a function of $x$ or $y$:

$$ V(x, y, z) = V(z) $$

whether that qualifies as "canceling-out" is debatable. Note, the scalar nature $V$ is not really relevant--as rotational invariance is not at play. Nevertheless, it is defined by a single value at each point, and that value cannot depend on $x$ or $y$ because nothing in the problem changes under and transformation $(x, y) \rightarrow (x+\Delta x, y+ \Delta y)$.

Comment: You are talking about the field, the OP is talking about *potential*. So the answer is not "Yes", the answer is "the potential is a scalar, not a vector". Otherwise, very good answer.